# Multi-Page app Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm an Android beginner and I'm developing an app that have this layout

[image: layout]

And now I need to create the content for every section of the app, and I wondered what is the best way to do that.

Reading the documentation I think it is better to use Fragments, but around the net I saw also swap layouts directly in the main activity. 
There are any advantages by using one way or another?

Comment: Check this link https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fragments as described in the documentation here [Drawer Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout).

The advantage is that you don't need to manage the swipe detection by yourself and that each time you swipe away a fragment it follows his normal life cycle and release his resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, you can create a new project and choose `Navigation Drawer Activity`. This will create a new project with the same layout you want, and you can change the content in the activity using fragments.